# How to remove RFH2 header for a JMS Point to Point Sampler in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jms, ibm-mq

We are trying to send a message to IBM MQ using JMS Point to Point Sampler in JMeter. After sending the message we can see that in the response queue an extra RFH header is getting added like this -

```
WRN Encountered invalid data from source 'HttpXmlObjectConverter' in data: RFH ▒▒MQSTR   ▒ <mcd><Msd>jms_text</Msd></mcd>  `<jms><Dst>queue:///quenename</Dst><Tms>1607427843324</Tms><Dlv>2</Dlv></jms>"
```

After searching on Google I found out that `targetClient` should be changed to `1` or `MQ`.

Any idea where we need to modify this? In JMeter or in Queue? If it is in JMeter then how to do that? I tried doing it in JMS and JNDI properties, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can configure the queue not to supply the RFH2 headers to getters who don't know how to handle them by using this command:

```
ALTER QLOCAL('quenename16074278433242') PROPCTL(NONE)
```

Comment: @HirenPatel - which part didn't work? Did the command fail or did the application still receive the RFH2 headers, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [targetClient](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032240_.html) property in the queue name:

```
queue:///quenename16074278433242?targetClient=1
```

Or you use [TARGCLIENT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.2.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q112610_.html) property in the JNDI configuration for JMSAdmin tool:

```
def q(yourJndiName) qu(quenename16074278433242) qmgr(yourQmgrName) targclient(MQ)
```